# Error: ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting the error:

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

For this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    [Theme].[Name], [ThemeType].[Type] 
FROM 
    [Theme] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [ThemeType] ON [Theme].[ThemeTypeId] = [ThemeType].[PK_ThemeType]
JOIN 
    [ProductTheme] ON [ProductTheme].[ThemeId]=[Theme].[PK_Theme]
WHERE 
    ProductTheme.ProductID LIKE '%' 
    AND ProductTheme.ThemeId = Theme.PK_Theme 
    AND COALESCE([THEME].[THEMETYPEID], 'null') LIKE '%[0-9]%' 
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN [THEMETYPE].[TYPE] IS NULL 
           THEN 0 
           ELSE 1 
    END, [THEMETYPE].[TYPE]
```

I have look into it and not defining the cases seems to be a common problem but I do. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @David: Try including entire CASE statement you have in ORDER BY into SELECT as well

Comment: What kind of values does your `ThemeType.Type` column have? Could you maybe use something like `ISNULL(ThemeType.Type, -99999)` in the `SELECT` and `ORDER BY` clauses to make sure the `NULL`s come first?

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the `CASE` *expression*. Won't `NULL`s sort first anyway?

Comment: So you want nulls to be sorted in the output but not display as 1 or 0? It seems you should be putting the case in the select list and then ordering by that.

Comment: I want nulls to be listed first and non-nulls to be listed second. Within these two sections I want the rows to be listed in alphabetical order by [Theme].[Name]

Comment: Your existing query doesn't order by [Theme].[Name] at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than use SELECT DISTINCT, use GROUP BY (to match the sort order specified in the comments):

```
SELECT 
    [Theme].[Name], [ThemeType].[Type] 
FROM 
    [Theme] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [ThemeType] ON [Theme].[ThemeTypeId] = [ThemeType].[PK_ThemeType]
JOIN 
    [ProductTheme] ON [ProductTheme].[ThemeId]=[Theme].[PK_Theme]
WHERE 
    ProductTheme.ProductID LIKE '%' 
    AND ProductTheme.ThemeId = Theme.PK_Theme 
    AND COALESCE([THEME].[THEMETYPEID], 'null') LIKE '%[0-9]%' 
GROUP BY
    [Theme].[Name], [ThemeType].[Type] 
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN [ThemeType].[Type] IS NULL 
           THEN 0 
           ELSE 1 
    END, [Theme].[Name]
```